# type conversion when using Numeric

Tags: scala

I am trying to find a safe way to convert concrete type Int, Long, Double back to type T for the next code.

So the question would be if there is an alternative to convert to type T instead of using isInstanceOf ?

```
   def transform[T](x: T)(implicit e: Numeric[T]): T = {
        x match {
          case xInt: Int =>
            // some manipulation with x
            val y = xInt + 1 
            e.fromInt(y)
          case xLong: Long =>
            val y = xLong + 2
            y.asInstanceOf[T]
            // is there a way to convert from Long or any other numeric type 
            // like above for Int -> fromInt?
          case xDouble =>
            // same pattern
          case _ => throw new Error("Type not supported")
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The key idea of a type class such as `Numeric` is to act as a kind of compile-time pattern matching which replaces run-time pattern matching. Usually there is no need to mix the two, so just call the methods on the type class instance and compiler will know the return type is `T`, for example

```
def transform[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = {
  num.plus(a, b)
}

transform(41.0, 1.0) // : Double = 42.0
transform(41, 1)     // : Int = 42
transform("41", "1") // compile-time error
```

or to get the syntactic sugar

```
import Numeric.Implicits._

def transform[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = {
  a + b
}
```

Comment: well, unfortunately I have to match type in the style above and do more interesting transformation with value of type Int, Long, Double etc, so as I understand there is no way I can convert concrete  type Int, Long, Double .. etc back to T but to use isIstanceOf ??

Comment: @Pavel that doesn't make sense, why you need to know the concrete type? You the want to write your own **typeclass** to use over _(or with)_ `Numeric`

Comment: put it different way, if I can apply conversion from concrete numeric type back to type of T? based on the fact that they have .fromInt method in Numeric, we can for Int but not other types, so asInstanceOf is the only choice as I can see.

Comment: @Pavel again, why you need that? The fact that you combine a **typeclass** with class checks means a design error. You either need to rethink your logic or need a different **typeclass**. - We may help if you can explain what is your problem.

Comment: its is likely I using type class Numeric in the wrong way, the only design restriction I would like to apply is: type T must be numeric: one of Long or Double or Int, so this way I am trying to avoid duplicate code which would deal with Long and Double separately